# Can we use the partial amount of cap in crowdloan?

Tags: crowdloan

if we run a crowdloan and say hit the cap of 500k DOT are we then forced to use its entirety to bid for the slot or we can use a subset of it?

In that maybe we could potentially exclude some people and reward others more.